# Possbible to measure accuracy of modeled distribution with only one observation from real distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, model, accuracy

I have a set of polling data.  Each day, the result of a 7-day rolling sample of polling data is reported.  In this particular case, the respondents come from the same group of people (it's technically a panel, rather than a poll).  So for each new day, in theory, I know which responses are falling out of the rolling window as well as who could possibly participate in the current day's polling.  Therefore, I can simulate a range of possible samples in part by using respondent's past behavior.

Based on this, I can model a distribution of expected outcomes.  So my model might say, for instance, that on a given day option A will poll higher than option B by 3 points 30% of the time, by 2 points 25% of the time, and so forth.

My question is how can I measure the accuracy of this model, given that I only ever see one observation from the real distribution?

Both my model's distribution and the real distribution change from day to day, and I have many days of data with which to work.  In my uneducated head, it seems like it should be possible to measure whether things my model say should happen 30% of the time actually happen 30% of time or not.

What is the formal way to measure accuracy in this situation?